# how to extract numbers from excel cell in the form of "x - y"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The cell is in the format of "6:00 - 14:00"; showing hours worked in 24 hour format. I would like a way to convert that in a way so I can perform operations with them.

I'm thinking if I can extract the "6:00" to a single cell with time format, and the same with the "14:00". Maybe I can use =RIGHT()/LEFT() but the number of characters would change each time as it is 24-hours format.

Any thoughts? \

Comment: The answer by @Skin works.  You can also use the 'Text to Columns' feature and choose 'Delimited' and then split on the '-' character.  You just need to make sure you have an empty column next to it so it can split between the two columns.  Don't use this if you need to keep your original field untouched though.

Answer (score 2):

Even with a 24-hours notation, you could still extract the 1st 5 and last 5 characters with `LEFT()` and `RIGHT()` since you use a leading and trailing space with the hyphen:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=--LEFT(A1,5)
```

Formula in `C1`:

```
=--RIGHT(A1,5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the value is in cell A1, to find the **6:00** ...

```
=TRIM(LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1) - 1))
```

... and to find the **14:00**...

```
=TRIM(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1) + 1,100))
```

Answer (score 1):

`FILTERXML()` would be a good choice in this case.

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($A$1,"-","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[1]")
```

Above formula will extract first part of time and will return as time value. If you need to format it as time then use `TEXT()` function like-

```
=TEXT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($A$1,"-","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[1]"),"hh:mm:ss")
```

To extract second part just change `[1]` to `[2]` like-

```
=TEXT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($A$1,"-","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[2]"),"hh:mm:ss")
```

[image]